# data.table filter list column for empty values

Tags: r, filter, data.table

Can I filter by a list-column in a `data.table` for the rows with empty lists?

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = list(c("A", "B"), character(0), c("C", "D", "E")))

> dt
a     b
1: 1   1,2
2: 2      
3: 3 1,2,3
```

i.e. the expected result is

```
> dt[filter(b)]
   a b
1: 2
```

The obvious filtering doesn't work

```
> dt[length(b) == 0]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b

> dt[length(b[[1]]) == 0]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
```

I thought I might be able to define a function to result in the right boolean value, but as I have to use a group by to make it actually work, it doesn't work in the filter argument

```
is_null_list = function(l) is.list(l) & length(l[[1]]) == 0

> dt[, is_null_list(b), a]
a    V1
1: 1 FALSE
2: 2  TRUE
3: 3 FALSE

> dt[is_null_list(b)]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
```

I guess the more general question is also, can any filtering be done on `data.table` list columns? I suspect the answer is no as you can't key by a list, but thought it was worth asking.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want `lengths(b)`? (Note the `s` on the end.)

Comment: Awesome + perfect.  Add as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: For anyone looking, it's made obvious from `?lengths` that the general version of filtering by list columns would be something like `dt[sapply(col, boo_func)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by the length of each element of a list column with `lengths`. For example,

```
dt[ lengths(b) == 0L ]
```